# What version of linux server is widely used by cassandra developers?

Tags: linux, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have plane to implement Cassandra 3.x on Linux server. There are many version of Linux server which is released (Ubuntu , Red Hat, Debian and ...). What version of Linux server we should use to get the best performance of Cassandra? 
It is the only factor which is important for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Cassandra I don't think which Linux distro you choose will really affect your performance that much. I suppose each Distro will have different OS tuning parameters... but you can change these. Basically any modern Linux distro will do just fine. Of course picking popular distros based on Debian or Fedora/RHEL means there will be more information out there to help you.

I would first start with [Recommended production settings for Linux](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installRecommendSettings.html). But honestly the biggest part to effectively using Cassandra for performance is using a proper Data Model.

Comment: I would stick with the newest Ubuntu LTS, RHEL, or CentOS 7 since they are probably the most widely used.

Comment: TNX @fromanator, I'm really looking for the one with ease of installation and use, reach support information?